# Run callbacks in Javascript in if else statement

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code snippet and when my `$remainingTime` becomes zero, I want it to run the stop function in callbacks. I don't know what I have to write in the else statement.

```
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(
  <?php
  $now = new DateTime('now');
  $tm = new DateTime('2017-12-22 12:00:00');
  $remainingTime = $tm->getTimestamp()-$now->getTimestamp();
  if($remainingTime>0) {
    echo $remainingTime;
  } else {
  }
  ?>
  ,{
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      $(".timerContainer").css('display','none');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: are you trying to run `stop` after some time, to say after 30 minutes

Comment: @msoliman i want to the variable $remainingTime is larger than 0 .echo $remaingTime otherwise it runs stop callback

Comment: you can do all of this in javascript, why you're using php inbetween, I can write for you in javascript if you want

Comment: @msoliman would you tell me to do this with js?

Comment: `$remainingTime` is a variable on the server, Javascript runs on the client. The variable is gone by the time the Javascript runs.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the `FlipClock` plugin you're using? When I google it there are lots of different ones, and I can't find one that has parameters like the ones you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `setInterval` and count until you reach your time:
for example, a code snippet to run for 10 seconds:

```js
    var i = 10;
    var end = 15;
    var statusDiv = document.getElementById("status");
    
    var t = setInterval(function(){ 
      if(i++ >= end) {
        clearInterval(t);
        stop();
       }
       statusDiv.innerHTML = i;
    }, 1000);
    
    
    function stop(){
      alert("stopped, Now 'i' equals " + i);
    }
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
```

I am not sure what `FlipClock` is doing but it seems it is like a counter but here is how to do the same as what you are doing in PHP which is not needed, If you want to get date and do date subtractions in JavaScript, check the following snippet:

```
var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
var d2 = new Date("December 23, 2017 01:13:00")  // some date
//var d2= new Date(2017,12,23,1,13,0);//same as d2 above
var remainingTime = Math.abs(d1-d2);  // get the diff in milliseconds
```

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to what he's doing. It doesn't use the PHP variable `$remainingTime`, it doesn't show how to code it in the callback of the `FlipClock` plugin.

Comment: The plugin presumably has its own interval timer to update the clock.

Comment: @msoliman i want to set specific time like my php code and i want to ir runs the stop callback that exists. you create a function stop yourself

Comment: @Barmar actually he is calculating `$remainingTime` using Php to inject and use it in javascript so I asked him to use javascript as long as it can be done using javascript

Comment: @sinak so you want to add specific time like an end time, in other words starting from now till that future specified time?

Answer (score 0):

Put the check after the plugin code.

```
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(
  <?php
  $now = new DateTime('now');
  $tm = new DateTime('2017-12-22 12:00:00');
  $remainingTime = $tm->getTimestamp()-$now->getTimestamp();
  if($remainingTime>0) {
    echo $remainingTime;
  } else {
  }
  ?>
  ,{
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      $(".timerContainer").css('display','none');
    }
  }
});
<?php if ($remainingTime == 0) {
    ?>
    $(".timerContainer").hide();
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mix JS and PHP that way. You could do something like:

```
<script>
  function runClock(remainingTime) {
    $('.clock').FlipClock(remainingTime, {
      clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
      countdown: true,
      onStop: function () {
        $(".timerContainer").css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<?php
$now = new DateTime('now');
$tm = new DateTime('2017-12-22 12:00:00');
$remainingTime = $tm->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp();
if ($remainingTime > 0) {
  echo "<script> runClock(" . $remainingTime . ");</script>";
}
?>
```